# Cron job fails: Could not retrieve file stat (script works when not run from cron)

Tags: shell-script, cron, aws, database

I have a database backup script that works fine when I run it manually, but if I run it via cron it doesn't work and I get this in the log:

```
Mar 11 11:58:02 ip-172-XX-Y-ZZ mysqldump: Could not retrieve file stat of "/home/admin/-": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/admin/-'
Mar 11 11:58:02 ip-172-XX-Y-ZZ mysqldump: mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Note: aws credentials are set with `aws configure` after installing aws cli
mysqldump -umysqldumpuser -pmysqldumpuserpassword --all-databases | gzip -c | aws s3 cp - s3://s3-bucket-name/mysql/all-databases--`date +%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S%Z`.sql.gz
```

crontab includes this:

```
58 0 * * * ~/scripts/mysqldump-all-databases-to-aws-s3.sh 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t mysqldump
```

This is a Debian Jessie server on AWS LightSail. I have the same script and crontab on a server running Amazon Linux and it works okay on that one.

I did change the timezone on the Debian server to my local timezone, while on the Amazon Linux server it is set to UTC. Maybe that is causing a problem with cron?

Do you know why this script is failing? Thanks.

Comment: Usually an environmental issue; are there variables set during a interactive session that are required? (AWS credentials?)

Comment: I just noticed that the log is recording 11:58, but the job runs at 00:58. This is the difference between UTC and my timezone. Is that normal?

Comment: Hurray, daylight savings!

Comment: out of interest, can you run gzip on any file?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's `aws s3 cp` [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No worries

Comment: @DeclanGallagher Do you mean is gzip working on this system? Yes, it's working normally

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't set any variables when I log in and run the script manually. The AWS credentials are persistent.

Comment: @Matt - in order to debug the problem, can you try and replace the `s3` output file (`s3://s3-bucket-name/mysql...`) with a locate file in a local folder (which have enough disk space for this file - prefer `/tmp` as it will allow any user to write to that folder)?

Comment: @Matt - note the error "'/home/admin/- No such file" - I wonder if the source of the error is the `-` in the `s3 cp` command

Comment: @Matt - are you running as user `admin`? do you run the `cron` as user `admin`?

Comment: @Yaron Thanks. Saving to a local file does work. Now I am sure the problem is something to do with the `-` in the `aws s3 cp`, but the script does work when run manually. Yes `admin` is my normal user and I just do `crontab -e`, no sudo or root cron jobs.

Comment: @Matt - another debug question - I'd like to debug the aws s3 access - can you add another `cron` which will execute a script which will include only the following line (or similar line) `aws s3 ls s3://s3-bucket-name/mysql/ > /tmp/s3_ls_test.txt` - can you let us know if the the `ls` output was saved into the the file in `/tmp`?

Comment: @Yaron Yes, the `aws s3 ls` script works as a cron job. I actually have a work around to my problem now by doing it in 3 steps: dump the database to a temp file; copy the temp file to S3; delete the temp file. That works. Still curious as to what caused the error in my original script but this will do for now. Time for bed :) Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: @matt - I suspect that your '-' was replaced with a Unicode version of '-'. Can you edit the script file using text editor, delete the '-' and replace it with a new '-' ?